# I am trying to save the result of show con_name to a variable in ORACLE PL/SQL SQLPLUS

Tags: plsql, sqlplus, oracle19c

I want to write something like this:

`exec SHOW CON_NAME into :=connection_name`

but this doesnt work.

I know I can do this but I want to know for future reference if there is any way to do this for show

`EXEC SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CON_NAME') into :connection_name from DUAL;`

Comment: The second one should work; but it's [`'USERENV'`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/USERENV.html) not `'USER_ENV'`.

Comment: Thank you. This gives me what I needed. AAAHHHHH Rookie mistake. This is why i am a goon. I will still ask the first question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exec` is just a wrapper for an anonymous block, so

```
exec SHOW CON_NAME into :=connection_name
```

is the same as

```
begin SHOW CON_NAME into :=connection_name end
```

Even with other issues fixed, `show` is a SQL*Plus client command, and doesn't mean anything inside a SQL or PL/SQL context.

You could do:

```
exec :connection_name := SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CON_NAME');
```

to avoid the context switch of selecting from dual within the PL/SQL.

Looking at the statement log in SQL Developer, `show con_name` is doing something similar, with a `checkone` bind variable it uses internally; though it also puts it through a local PL/SQL variable and trims that to 30 chars.

You could also use `column ... new_value ...`  and query from dual, without using PL/SQL, and then use a substitution variable to refer to the value later instead of a bind variable:

```
column con_name new_value connection_name
select SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CON_NAME') as con_name from dual;

-- then later...
select '&connection_name' from dual;
```

Not sure how useful that would be though. Depends what you want to use it for I suppose.